# git merge: Does it matter which commit is newer?

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose I have two commmits, A and B. Suppose I am merging B into A. Does it matter whether A or B is the more recent commit? Or will I get the same result independent of the timestamps?

Comment: Do you mean branches? You don't typically merge one commit into another

Comment: @Phil I changed  it to be about branches. But my mistake shows me I have more to learn about merges.

Comment: Actually Phil is wrong. You do merge commit. A branch is just the name of a commit.

Comment: @matt you don't merge a commit into a commit though. Commits are immutable

Comment: @Phil Sure, you don't technically merge commit B into commit A. But merge is an operation that takes two commits as an inputs (asymmetrically depending on which way the merge is going) and produces a third commit M. I think commits are the key ingredients. The branches are just along for the ride. At least that's how I think about it, and why I said "commit" instead of "branch" originally

Comment: @Phil yes you do. You nearly always name them as branches but there is no law about it. You can say `git merge <anyCommit>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will I get the same result independent of the timestamps?

Yes. A merge is performed by enacting simultaneously the "changes" on *both* sides since the point where the sides diverged. Both sides weigh 100% equally. It doesn't matter how they relate temporally or which side is being merged into which.

A common source of confusion, though, is failure to realize that *lack* of change on one side means *no* contribution. If the divergence point has Hey, and if one side now has Ho and the other side has Hey, the result of the merge will be Ho.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/